# How did i get the ALT Attribute from an image over xpath in php

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I try to get some informations from an external page. On some querstions here i found the right way with xpath. After checking the W3C School for the query-syntax i got the first elements without problems.

Now i try to get the value of a ALT - Image Tag and have problems. Here my code and output.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: wial
 * Date: 25.11.16
 * Time: 14:27
 */
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$typen = $finder->query('//dl[@class="dl-horizontal"]/dd/ul/li/a/img[@alt]')->item(0);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($typen, true) . '</pre>';
?>
```

The xpath works, i got the IMG element, but i dont know, how to get the ALT.

my output

```
DOMElement Object
(
    [tagName] => img
    [schemaTypeInfo] => 
    [nodeName] => img
    [nodeValue] => 
    [nodeType] => 1
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
    [firstChild] => 
    [lastChild] => 
    [previousSibling] => 
    [attributes] => (object value omitted)
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => img
    [baseURI] => //www.example.de/
    [textContent] => 
)
```

when i try

```
$typen = $finder->query('//dl[@class="dl-horizontal"]/dd/ul/li/a/img[@alt]')->item(0)->attributes;
```

i just got

```
DOMNamedNodeMap Object
(
    [length] => 2
)
```

where i lost the right way?

Br Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DOMElement` object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) has the [`getAttribute` method](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) that you can use in order to get the value of any attribute that DOMElement has:

```
$typen = $finder->query('//dl[@class="dl-horizontal"]/dd/ul/li/a/img[@alt]')->item(0);

var_dump($typen->getAttribute('alt'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that exactly what im looking for